# ActiveRecord equivalent to this

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

**Short version**

What's the SQL-only equivalent to

```
Workable.includes(:job_types)
        .where(job_types: {id: nil})
```

(answer of the form `Workable.includes(:job_types).where('SQLHERE', nil)`

**Long version**

I'm trying to 'OR' these two queries:

```
workables.includes(:job_types)
         .where('job_types.id = ?', params[:job_type])
         .references(:job_types)
```

and

```
Workable.includes(:job_types).where(job_types: {id: nil})
```

**Longer version, to clarify David's question below**

`Workables have_and_belong_to_many job_types`

I'm looking to find `Workables` where either the `id` matches the search parameter, or the `Workable` has no `job_types` at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If params[:job_type] is an integer, perhaps you could instead use:

```
workables.includes(:job_types)
         .where(:job_types => {:id => [params[:job_type], nil]})
```

Or are you looking for a situation where there is no corresponding job_type record at all?

Comment: Thanks David! I'm looking for a situation where there are no job_types